# shinydashboard - Sidebar toggle button doesn't work after update

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

After updating packages to the newest versions, sidebar toggle button has disappeared. It's not displayed properly (there should be 3 horizontal bars) and it doesn't work - clicking it doesn't make any action.

[image: sidebar toggle after packages update]

Previously it looked like this:

[image: sidebar toggle before packages update]

Here's the code:

```
  shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
  skin = "midnight",
  header = shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(
    title = shiny::h3(id = "h3-main-title", "My Shiny App")
  ),
  #   __________________________________________________________________________
  #   Sidebar                                                                ####
  sidebar = shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
    shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
      id = "sidebar_menu",
      #   ______________________________________________________________________
      #   Home                                                            ####
      shinydashboard::menuItem(
        "Home",
        tabName = "HOME",
        icon = shiny::icon("home")
      ),
      # rest of the code
    )
  )
)
```

Packages versions:

```
shiny: 1.6.0  
shinydashboard: 0.7.1  
shinydashboardPus: 2.0.0
```

During the change I've updated a lot of packages, could it be that one of them interferes with toggle button even though it isn't explicitly used in the code above?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  I have Shiny 1.5.0, and other packages are same.

Comment: Works also for me with exact same packages versions, R version 4.0.2 on Windows 10